# Keep only x number of images in directory, delete others with python code -- {closed }

Tags: python, directory

I have three main folders Train, Test and Val. In these, there are over 100 folders each. I want to limit the number of images to 90. if a folder contains over 90 images, delete rest images.

```
| dataset
|   | 
|   | Train
|   |   |
|   |   | Folder (1 of 112)
|   |   |   |
|   |   |   | Images
```

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: try to explore about `os` library. It will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import os 

if __name__ == "__main__": 

for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk('.', topdown=True): 

    print (root) 

    print (dirs) 

    print (files) 

    print ('--------------------------------')
```

you specify the path to search and it will return the files stored in the path in the form of a tuple of filenames, you find the length of the files tuple by using len function the use a if statement to delete all files above count 90

```
file_length=len(files)
if file_length>90:
    for i in range(91,file_length):
        os.remove(files[i])
```

here files[i] is for removing files after file index 91 and you need to add proper path before file index, which means if the file to be deleted is in images directory
you need to do it like os.remove("images//"+files[i])inside the loop

Comment: Thanks @aditya for the answer.. I tried this code and when i run it, I am getting a very unexpected error. It says filename not found even if it is clearly visible in the directory

Comment: Can you share the exact path of the directory and the path that you are providing in the os.remove command as this command is working on my computer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I tried the same by giving the path to directory + "/" + files[i].. it worked perfectly.. thanks!

Comment: Can you mark the answer as aceepted if possible